# Как убрать зеркальный градиент на border-color?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Сделал кнопку которая обведена бордером и при наведении должен заливаться фон градиентом и при этом делать бордер прозрачным, но так получается что как будто бордер копирует бэкеграунд и при этом зеркалит его.
При наведении, по бокам противоположные цвета заданые в градиенте

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;margin:35px 170px;
}


a.da {
    background: 0 0;
    border-color: #f2a309;
    color: #fff;
}

.btnn {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    padding: 8px 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
.da:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,#38acbf 0%,#f2a309 100%);
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnn da" href="#">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-origin: border-box;

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;margin:35px 170px;
}


a.da {
    background: 0 0;
    border-color: #f2a309;
    color: #fff;
}

.btnn {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    padding: 8px 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: .5s ease-out all;
    
}
.da:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,#38acbf 0%,#f2a309 100%);
    border-color: transparent;
    background-origin: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnn da" href="#">Read More</a>
```